# Can we use URL with access token to login Facebook in Browser

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

After login Facebook in my own Android App(use Facebook SDK), already the obtained access token, then click a icon link to related Facebook URL, in this way, user has to login Facebook in Browser again.

Can we use URL with access token to login Facebook in Browser?

Perhaps like this *www.facebook.com?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx...* ?

Any suggestion helps. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot log-in to Facebook using user's `access_token`. If it was allowed this would be major security issue!

`access_token` is bound to application (use [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to dig deeper in what data is associated with it) and only grant applications access to data user allowed to specific application `access_token` belongs to...

It's better for you to use [Single-Sign-On (SSO)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso) so authentication flow may be passed via native Facebook application, this isn't really help you to authenticate user in browser, but allowing to skip entry of user's credentials just to log-in to your app.

Comment: Thanks! It makes me confused for a long time. BTW, the Debug Tool is very useful.